# Applescript to select Move or Copy and to select Destination

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm somewhat knowledgable about Automator, but not at all knowledgable about Applescript. So, I'm trying to create an Applescript to do the following, since there’s likely no way to do it natively using only Automator.

Instead of creating numerous Services that would all appear in the Services menu like this:

Copy to Destination A

Move to Destination A

Copy to Destination B

Move to Destination B

Copy to Destination C

Move to Destination C

I’d like to create one Automator that would do the following.  As soon as the Workflow is started, I’d get the following options:

Move or Copy

Once I make a selection, I’d get the following menu:  Select one of the following:

Destination A

Destination B

Destination C

Once I select a destination and click OK, my file would either to moved or copied to the selected destination.  What would be a good way to do this using Applescript?

Answer (score 0):

In pure Applescript, you can use  "display dialog " for this. You could also use choose from list or chose folder.

```
set theMethod to button returned of (display dialog "Move or Copy" buttons {"move", "copy"})
set theDestination to button returned of (display dialog "Select your destination" buttons {"Destination A", "Destination B", "Destination"})
-- or use choose folder:
--set theDestination to (choose folder with prompt "Select your destination")
-- or use choose from list:
--choose from list {"Destination A", "Destination B", "Destination"}

display dialog (theMethod & " to " & theDestination)
```

Comment: Dang, got too busy and forgot about this.  Yeah, this seem to fit the bill with what I'm looking to do. Thanks much!